# How to choose the best technique for handling imbalanced data for binary classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, imbalanced-data

I am working on my thesis on imbalanced dataset for binary classification problem. I need to handle the imbalance on data before make the classification, but I am not sure what technique is better to choose. I search on google and found many technique, such as SMOTE, cost sensitive learning, hybrid and ensemble techniques. This actually make me confused. I did not know How to choose the best.

Also, when I tried SMOTE, it just increase the precision metric, but decrease the other metrics, such as recall, accuracy and f1-score. I expect that all metrics will be increased after handling imbalanced data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with SMOTE is overgeneralization: in a nutshell, it creates new points that are in the line joining two existing points of the minority class. This helps in some situations, but it might not generate enough variability for your classifier to learn properly. Have you tried using [synthetic data](https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-synthetic) for oversampling? It helps maintain your data characteristics better than SMOTE